I need help in configuring TailwindCSS and Vite to execute external CSS in monorepo
I am trying to setup a monorepo for my frontend projects. As my first project i only have html file. And this is how my project structure looks like: -
Project Structure
As you can see my index.css file is outside of apps/moveit directory where index.html is.
This is my html file: -
Index.html
This is tailwind.config.js file: -
tailwind.config.js
This is vite.config.js file: -
vite.config.js
I am using pnpm as package manager.
As you can see I have a lot of things going on in vite.config.js file. That's because I was trying all the suggestions I was getting from chatgpt, gemini, perplexity. But so far I couldn't figure out how to make it work.
I tried moving index.css file inside apps/moveit and it works, but problem is that I want to have a common CSS file for all my future projects in this monorepo (or atleast I think it is one). So, don't want to place it in apps/moveit.
Let me know if you need any more information from me. Any suggestion is appreaciated. Thanks in advance.
